# how can I calculate new column based on pandas conditions of multiple previous values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have the following dataframe.
How can I create a new column based on the following:
if, for example, the row of 19:24 has a diff < .1
AND the row of 19:21 has a diff of < .1
then create new column and set row equal to say 1

I know how I can do these with if statements, but i'm stuck on trying to use a pandas (more efficient) solution for this.

```
                    open     high      low    close      diff                   
TimeStamp                                                                           
2018-10-05 19:00:00  6637.90  6645.06  6637.17  6643.52 -0.057705                   
2018-10-05 19:03:00  6643.52  6650.00  6641.00  6649.99  0.002710                   
2018-10-05 19:06:00  6648.91  6650.00  6640.82  6642.85 -0.017769                   
2018-10-05 19:09:00  6642.85  6646.47  6642.00  6646.20  0.000000                   
2018-10-05 19:12:00  6646.20  6646.21  6642.00  6642.40  0.085065                   
2018-10-05 19:15:00  6641.00  6641.84  6636.35  6638.54 -0.024863                   
2018-10-05 19:18:00  6639.26  6643.38  6638.00  6640.00 -0.067340                   
2018-10-05 19:21:00  6642.49  6643.82  6642.47  6643.63  0.104931                   
2018-10-05 19:24:00  6643.78  6645.31  6635.50  6640.02 -0.031497
```

Comment: [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) is the key. If you provide a minimal working example, people might be able to help you better.

Comment: df['new_column'] = df['diff'].lt(0.1).astype(int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html), and the `&` operator to combine two Boolean series.

This will set `flag = 1` for every instance where `diff < 0.1` on a row where that row *and the preceding row* both satisfy the condition.

```
df['flag'] = (df['diff'].lt(0.1) & df['diff'].shift().lt(0.1)).astype(int)
```

Possibly more efficient would be to use `shift` on a single comparison:

```
s = df['diff'].lt(0.1)
df['flag'] = (s & s.shift()).astype(int)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

                        open     high      low    close      diff  flag
TimeStamp                                                              
2018-10-05 19:00:00  6637.90  6645.06  6637.17  6643.52 -0.057705     0
2018-10-05 19:03:00  6643.52  6650.00  6641.00  6649.99  0.002710     1
2018-10-05 19:06:00  6648.91  6650.00  6640.82  6642.85 -0.017769     1
2018-10-05 19:09:00  6642.85  6646.47  6642.00  6646.20  0.000000     1
2018-10-05 19:12:00  6646.20  6646.21  6642.00  6642.40  0.085065     1
2018-10-05 19:15:00  6641.00  6641.84  6636.35  6638.54 -0.024863     1
2018-10-05 19:18:00  6639.26  6643.38  6638.00  6640.00 -0.067340     1
2018-10-05 19:21:00  6642.49  6643.82  6642.47  6643.63  0.104931     0
2018-10-05 19:24:00  6643.78  6645.31  6635.50  6640.02 -0.031497     0
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for helping with this! This will definitely help out my project.